# How to use pandas and Numpy data transformations within a Python function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to perform some simple transformations using pandas and NumPy inside a function. The transformations required are:

1. Remove 'Verified' column from df
2. Convert array into a dataframe (df2)
3. Merge the two dfs together

I've copied my code below. It works fine outside a function but I don't know how to make it work within a function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "John", True], [2, "Ann", False]], columns=["Id", "Login", "Verified"])
array = np.array([[1, 987340123], [2, 187031122]], np.int32)


df.drop(columns=['Verified'], inplace = True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=id_password, index=["0", "1"], columns=["Id", "Password"])
df = df.merge(df2, how = 'inner')

print(df)
```

I'm sure there's a really simple solution but I'm completely stuck and a beginner. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem may be using print() in the function, you should return the dataframe instead

```
def fun(df, array):
    df.drop(columns=['Verified'], inplace = True)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=array, index=["0", "1"], columns=["Id", "Password"])
    df = df.merge(df2, how = 'inner')

    return(df)
```

you can then print the result of calling the function

```
print(fun(df, array))
```

Output:

```
   Id Login   Password
0   1  John  987340123
1   2   Ann  187031122
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. That's exactly what I was looking for - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to merge the `df` (without `Verified` column) and the `array`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, "John", True], [2, "Ann", False]], columns=["Id", "Login", "Verified"]
)
array = np.array([[1, 987340123], [2, 187031122]], np.int32)

df_out = pd.merge(
    df.drop(columns="Verified"),
    pd.DataFrame(array, columns=["Id", "Password"]),
    on="Id",
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   Id Login   Password
0   1  John  987340123
1   2   Ann  187031122
```

Comment: Thanks - yeah I wanted to merge the df and array WITHIN a function. Patrick (other commenter) pointed out that you need to print the function instead of just the df: print(fun(df, array))